# Intuition behind the definition of irreducible polynomials in Gallain

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

The book on Abstract Algebra by Gallian defines "irreducible polynomials" as :

> Let $D$ be an integral domain. A polynomial $f(x)$ from $D[x]$ that is
> neither the zero polynomial nor a unit in $D[x]$ is said to be irreducible
> over $D$ if, whenever $f(x)$ is expressed as a product $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, with
> $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ from $D[x]$, then $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ is a unit in $D[x]$.

I can't understand why $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ has to be a unit in $D[x]$. How will that change things ?

This brings me to another question on a following example:

> The polynomial $f(x) = 2x^2 + 4$ is irreducible over $Q$
> but reducible over $Z$, since $2(x^2+2)$ and neither $2$ nor $x^2+2$
> is a unit in Z[x].

Again, what is the intuition behind wanting the factors to be non-units ?

Basically, I just want to know the logic behind such a definition. Any help shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: Compare to the prime integers: a prime can only be factored as itself times one.

Comment: Would you consider $3$ a composite number because $3=(-1)(-3)$? In general, if $f$ is any element of a ring and $u$ is a unit with inverse $v$, then $f=u(vf)$ would mean all elements are reducible ... unless you exclude units from being factors in the definition.

Comment: To provide another example: if you didn't require factorisation into non-units, then in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ almost anything you can think of would be reducible. E.g. $x^2 + x + 1 = (1/57) \times (57x^2 + 57x +57)$ is a silly example. But $1/57$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ because it is invertible (with inverse $57$) thus we don't count this as a valid factorisation.

Comment: An additional comment on your example: $2$ is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$ because it has no inverse. (Its inverse would be $1/2$ but of course this is not in $\mathbb{Z}$. Whereas $1/2$ is indeed in $\mathbb{Q}$ so 2 is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}$ and thus the $\mathbb{Q}$ factorisation isn't a valid one. Hope this helps.